# User registration and profile changes do not work on site with Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, users

I'm working on a site that uses Expresso Store for e-commerce. The store itself seems to work fine, however there are templates that use exp:user to register and update a user's profile that are not working as intended - upon submitting the register or update form, the page redirects to a blank page and does not register the user or update profiles of existing users. It seems at this point to be some conflict with Expresso Store, but I'm not sure where...

The site uses an SSL certificate for all sections, and both register and edit profile forms have secure_action="yes".

Expression Engine build is 2.5.5, Store is 1.6.4, and User is 3.3.9. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The .htaccess file:

### Solspace Static Page Caching: Site #1

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //www.vandykblueberries.ca/
```

### RULE #1 - gzip

```
## Accepts GZ output
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip

## Ignore POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST

## Ignore EE Query requests
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(css|ACT)

## Override Cookie That Disables Caching
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(static_page_caching_override).*$

## Override Segment for ToolBar
RewriteCond $1 !spc_override/*$

## Remove the index.php from the next conditional check, neutralize slashes
RewriteCond $1 ^(index.php/)*(.*)(/*)$

## Cache File Exists?
RewriteCond /home/vandykbl/www/manage/expressionengine/cache/1/$2/index.html.gz -f

## Redirect to Cache File
RewriteRule ^(index.php/*)*(.*)(/*) //www.vandykblueberries.ca/cache/1/$2/index.html.gz [L]
```

### RULE #2 - normal

```
## Ignore POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST

## Ignore EE Query requests
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(css|ACT)

## Override Cookie That Disables Caching
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(static_page_caching_override).*$

## Override Segment for ToolBar
RewriteCond $1 !spc_override/*$

## Remove the index.php from the next conditional check, neutralize slashes
RewriteCond $1 ^(index.php/)*(.*)(/*)$

## Cache File Exists?
RewriteCond /home/vandykbl/www/manage/expressionengine/cache/1/$2/index.html -f

## Redirect to Cache File
RewriteRule ^(index.php/*)*(.*)(/*) //www.vandykblueberries.ca/cache/1/$2/index.html [L]
```

### RULE #3 - Remove SPC Override Segment from URI

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/spc_override$ //www.vandykblueberries.ca/$1 [L]
```

### END Solspace Static Page Caching: Site #1

RewriteEngine On

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you post your htaccess? Also if you have a link to a site where we can see this happening it would be super helpful.

Comment: Hi there Adrian - apologies for the late reply, I didn't realize this had been responded to. The site in question is vandykblueberries.ca, though the register/update views are hidden at the moment - if you send me an email at brian@headspacedesign.ca I can get you an EE login to take a look.

Comment: Hi Brian, can you email us at support@exp-resso.com and provide us with access? We'll hop in and have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Store would be at fault here. It sounds like a problem with the register/update forms in Solspace User.

The first step I would take to debug is to uninstall Store (back up your data first!), and see whether you can get the User forms working on their own.